# Pointing domain(registered at godaddy) to static IP address

Tags: linux, website, webserver

I want to host one website on apache server which is installed in my local HP machine.I want to map it to my domain name ex. www.xxx.com purchased at godaddy.com.Do i need to install dns server?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't suggest it. Instead, just use your registrar's DNS servers. Click on the [DNS Manager](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/680/managing-dns-for-your-domain-names) link in GoDaddy's control panel.

Comment: That means do i need to take hosting account there or i can host my website in my local server  and bind my static ip to that domain?

Comment: You can host any services your domain provides any place you want.

Comment: Good reply @DavidSchwartz

Answer (score 0):

Create A host record in your godaddy DNS Zone File settings
[Tutorial by godaddy help section](https://in.godaddy.com/help/updating-your-domain-names-ip-address-for-forwarding-5289)